# Mongoose update query with $pull not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to remove a specific notification from User but it is not working.

Query:

```
User.updateOne(
        { name: req.userData.name },
        {
          $pull: {
            notification: {_id: req.body.notif._id},
          },
        }
      )
```

In the response it even says that it had matched a value but for some reason did not modify it.

Response:

```
"response": {
    "acknowledged": true,
    "modifiedCount": 0,
    "upsertedId": null,
    "upsertedCount": 0,
    "matchedCount": 1
}
```

Schema:

```
mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
name: String,
password: { type: String, required: true},
notification: []
```

Example document:

```
 {
    "_id": "61b642d85f7455eef2004721",
    "name": "User1",
    "password": "password",
    "__v": 0,
    "notification": [
        {
            "_id": "61bf602f87ff23e9d8858a59",
            "from": "User2",
            "time": "Sun Dec 19 2021 16:39:11 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "type": "friend-request"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: post your schema and example document in your question.

Comment: The matchedCount shows you that your first queryObject worked out, but it seems that something with your $pull statement is wrong

Comment: what is your `req.body.notif._id`? if you look here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gP9CHw8h1PO the code works

Comment: req.body.notif._id is just an id a copied from the notification - "61bf602f87ff23e9d8858a59"

Comment: Are you sure the `_id` fields in the `notifications` array contain string and not objectId

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with trying to match string to objectId.
After changing the code to the following it works fine.
Thank you for your help.

```
User.updateOne(
    { name: req.userData.name },
    {
      $pull: {
        notification: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.notif._id)},
      },
    }
```

Comment: This though does not match with your question, since the question only provides a String in the _id field, make sure to always provide the correct types